# How to Extract Dataframe From Poorly-Formatted CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a bunch of weirdly-formatted CSVs that I need to extract some data from and put it into a dataframe. When I read the file as is by using `df = pd.read_csv(file)`, it looks like:

```
            A       B       C      D     E
0   Account 1     111      20     10  12.0
1   Account 2     222      30     15   NaN
2   Account 3     333      40     25   NaN
3         NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
4     Company    Name  Number  Price   NaN
5         AAA  AA Inc      15    100   NaN
6         NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
7     Company     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
8          BB  BB Inc       5     20   NaN
9          CC  CC Inc      20     50   NaN
10         AA  AA Inc      12    100   NaN
```

But there's a lot of data that isn't needed, as I want the output to look like:

```
    Company    Name  Number  Price
0        AA  AA Inc      15    100
1        BB  BB Inc       5     20
2        CC  CC Inc      20     50
3        AA  AA Inc      12    100
```

I can't use indexes because there are multiple CSVs and the desired data doesn't always start on the same row so the program needs be fairly flexible. I know I could write a bunch of functions w/ special rules, but this seems prone to error and tedious.

So is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Could you do the alignment work in Excel? That might be best if this is a one-off solution. If you need to do this a bunch of times with many different CSV files, you might want to go for your "tedious" version, perhaps mapping out the headers for each.

Comment: I'd rather not do it in Excel, but sounds like I don't have much of an option

Comment: Is the column "Name" always "Inc" for the rows you want? If yes then this should be just the filter usage

Comment: No, I think the markdown misformatted the "Name" column, and the values are "AA Inc", "BB Inc", etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data_string = '''Account 1,111,20,10,12.0
Account 2,222,30,15,NaN
Account 3,333,40,25,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
Company,Name,Number,Price,NaN
AAA,AA Inc,15,100,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
Company,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
BB,BB Inc,5,20,NaN
CC,CC Inc,20,50,NaN
AA,AA Inc,12,100,NaN'''

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [x.split(',') for x in data_string.split('\n')],
    columns=list('ABCDE')).replace('NaN', np.nan)
print(df, '\n\n----\n')

first_row = df['A'].to_list().index('Company')
df = df.iloc[first_row:, :4]
df.columns = df.iloc[0].values
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df = df[df['Company'] != 'Company'].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            A       B       C      D     E
0   Account 1     111      20     10  12.0
1   Account 2     222      30     15   NaN
2   Account 3     333      40     25   NaN
3         NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
4     Company    Name  Number  Price   NaN
5         AAA  AA Inc      15    100   NaN
6         NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
7     Company     NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
8          BB  BB Inc       5     20   NaN
9          CC  CC Inc      20     50   NaN
10         AA  AA Inc      12    100   NaN

----

  Company    Name Number Price
0     AAA  AA Inc     15   100
1      BB  BB Inc      5    20
2      CC  CC Inc     20    50
3      AA  AA Inc     12   100
```